# Convert device pose to camera pose

Tags: matrix, depth, google-project-tango

I'm using the camera intrinsic (fx, fy, cx, cy, width, hight) to store a depth image of TangoXyzIjData.xyz buffer. Therefore I calculate for each point of xyz the corresponding image point and store its z value

```
x' = (fx * x) / z + cx
y' = (fy * y) / z + cy
depthImage[x'][y'] = z
```

Now I would like to store the corresponding pose data as well. I'm using the timestamp of TangoXyzIjData.timestamp and the following function

```
getPoseAtTime(double timestamp, TangoCoordinateFramePair framePair)
```

with framepair

```
new TangoCoordinateFramePair(TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE, TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE)
```

The problem is that the pose is the device frame wrt start of service frame. And the depth image get's its points from the depth camera frame. How can I match them?

There is a way to convert the depth camera points to the device frame by:

1. depth2IMU = depth camera frame wrt IMU frame
2. device2IMU = device frame wrt IMU frame
3. device2IMU^-1 = invert device frame wrt IMU frame
4. camera2Device = device2IMU^-1 * depth2IMU

Now I could multiply each point of the point cloud with camera2Device. But that's the transformation to the device frame.

Is there any way to convert the device pose to a camera pose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you put together is correct! But it's not finished.

---

### Format

To formalize the terminalogy, let's use `a_T_b` as a transformation matrix, where `a` represents the base frame, `b` represents the target frame. `a_T_b` is `a` frame with respect to `b` frame.

---

### Compute the matrix

Based on your question, the matrices we known are:

`start_service_T_device`, `imu_T_device` , `imu_T_depth`

The matrix we want to get is:

`start_service_T_depth`

We can just use a "matrix chain" to get the result:

```
start_service_T_depth = start_service_T_device * 
                        inverse(imu_T_device) * 
                        imu_T_depth;
```

Now, let's say we have a point `P_depth` in depth frame. To apply the pose for this point and convert it to `start_service` frame, we could use:

```
P_ss = start_service_T_depth * P_depth;
```

---

### Put it in OpenGL frame

In most of the cases, you might want to convert it to some coordate frame that is easy for graphic library to render out. Let's take OpenGL for example, we can transform this point to the OpenGL world coordinate frame as follow:

Note that `start_service_T_opengl_world` is a constant matrix that you could compute by hand. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango-gl/conversions.cpp#L22) is a link to the matrix, quoted from Project Tango c++ example.

```
P_gl = opengl_world_T_start_service * P_ss;
```

We can expand everything we just wrote and put it in a single equation:

```
P_gl = opengl_world_T_start_service * 
       start_service_T_device * 
       inverse(imu_T_device) * 
       imu_T_depth * 
       P_depth;
```

---

### Sample code from Project Tango

Also, in the project tango examples, the point cloud example has a pretty good explanation of these conversions, here are the links([c++](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/point-cloud-jni-example), [java](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java), [unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes sure if I would like to transpose the depth points to an open gl frame, that's the way it works. I only suggested how I transpose the points to the device frame to demonstrate the chain. But that wasn't the core problem. The problem I have is that I really want the points in the camera frame so that I can compute a depth image with the right resolution etc. But I also want to store a pose which represents the translation and rotation of the camera and not of the device frame.

Comment: I see your point. I think it can be solved in the similar method as well. First, the point cloud is already in the depth camera frame, if you want to transform it to color camera frame you should do: P_color = color_T_depth * P_depth;. This matrix is provides by Tango extrinsics API. Regarding to put a pose to the depth frame, I think the result matrix you want is start_service_T_depth, so the matrix chain should be like this: ss_T_depth = ss_T_device * device_T_imu * imu_T_depth; (ss is start of service).

Comment: by the way, have you looked at rgb-depth-sync-example from the Tango c API examples? I have a feeling that you are trying to implement some similar functionalities. That example might be helpful. Here's the link: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/rgb-depth-sync-example

Comment: Thanks that's really helpfull! The matrix chain has to compute like ((ss_T_device * device_T_imu) *imu_T_depth) right?
Last question.. how can I derive the pose from that matrix as a quaternion?
`float qw = (float) (Math.sqrt(1 + start_service_T_depth[0] + start_service_T_depth[5] + start_service_T_depth[10])/2);
        float qx = (start_service_T_depth[6] - start_service_T_depth[9])/(4*qw);
        float qy = (start_service_T_depth[8] - start_service_T_depth[2])/(4*qw);
        float qz = (start_service_T_depth[1] - start_service_T_depth[4])/(4*qw);`
.. looks bad. Have you any suggestions?