# Generate and export point cloud from Project Tango

Tags: android, google-project-tango, point-clouds

After some weeks of waiting I finally have my Project Tango. My idea is to create an app that generates a point cloud of my room and exports this to .xyz data. I'll then use the .xyz file to show the point cloud in a browser! I started off by compiling and adjusting the point cloud example that's on Google's github.

Right now I use the `onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData tangoXyzIjData)` to get a frame of x y and z values; the points. I then save these frames in a PCLManager in the form of `Vector3`. After I'm done scanning my room, I simple write all the `Vector3` from the PCLManager to a .xyz file using:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
size = pointCloud.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String row = String.valueOf(pointCloud.get(i).x) + " " 
               + String.valueOf(pointCloud.get(i).y) + " " 
               + String.valueOf(pointCloud.get(i).z) + "\r\n";
    os.write(row.getBytes());
}
os.close();
```

Everything works fine, not compilation errors or crashes. The only thing that seems to be going wrong is the rotation or translation of the points in the cloud. When I view the point cloud everything is messed up; the area I scanned is not recognizable, though the amount of points is the same as recorded.

Could this have to do something with the fact that I don't use PoseData together with the XyzIjData? I'm kind of new to this subject and have a hard time understanding what the PoseData exactly does. Could someone explain it to me and help me fix my point cloud?

Comment: The pose of the device is the viewpoint where the point cloud is captured. If you aren't using that pose, the point clouds are shown from the same viewpoint which is why everything seems messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `TangoPoseData`.

I guess you are using `TangoXyzIjData` correctly; but the data you get this way is relative to where the device is and how the device is tilted when you take the shot.

Here's how i solved this:
I started from [java_point_to_point_example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_point_to_point_example). In this example they get the coords of 2 different points with 2 different coordinate system and then write those coordinates wrt the base Coordinate frame pair.

First of all you have to setup your exstrinsics, so you'll be able to perform all the transformations you'll need. To do that I call `mExstrinsics = setupExtrinsics(mTango)` function at the end of my `setTangoListener()` function. Here's the code (that you can find also in the example I linked above).

```
private DeviceExtrinsics setupExtrinsics(Tango mTango) {
    //camera to IMU tranform
    TangoCoordinateFramePair framePair = new TangoCoordinateFramePair();
    framePair.baseFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU;
    framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR;
    TangoPoseData imu_T_rgb = mTango.getPoseAtTime(0.0,framePair);
    //IMU to device transform
    framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
    TangoPoseData imu_T_device = mTango.getPoseAtTime(0.0,framePair);
    //IMU to depth transform
    framePair.targetFrame = TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH;
    TangoPoseData imu_T_depth = mTango.getPoseAtTime(0.0,framePair);
    return new DeviceExtrinsics(imu_T_device,imu_T_rgb,imu_T_depth);
}
```

Then when you get the point Cloud you have to "normalize" it. Using your exstrinsics is pretty simple:

```
public ArrayList<Vector3> normalize(TangoXyzIjData cloud, TangoPoseData cameraPose, DeviceExtrinsics extrinsics) {
    ArrayList<Vector3> normalizedCloud = new ArrayList<>();

    TangoPoseData camera_T_imu = ScenePoseCalculator.matrixToTangoPose(extrinsics.getDeviceTDepthCamera());

    while (cloud.xyz.hasRemaining()) {
        Vector3 rotatedV = ScenePoseCalculator.getPointInEngineFrame(
                new Vector3(cloud.xyz.get(),cloud.xyz.get(),cloud.xyz.get()),
                camera_T_imu,
                cameraPose
        );
        normalizedCloud.add(rotatedV);
    }

    return normalizedCloud;
}
```

This should be enough, now you have a point cloud wrt you base frame of reference.
If you overimpose two or more of this "normalized" cloud you can get the 3D representation of your room.

There is another way to do this with rotation matrix, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949436/project-tango-rotation-and-translation-of-point-clouds-with-area-learning/38087697?noredirect=1#comment63646455_38087697).

My solution is pretty slow (it takes around 700ms to the dev kit to normalize a cloud of ~3000 points), so it is not suitable for a real time application for 3D reconstruction.

Atm i'm trying to use Tango 3D Reconstruction Library in C using NDK and JNI. The library is well documented but it is very painful to set up your environment and start using JNI. (I'm stuck at the moment in fact).

### Drifting

> There still is a problem when I turn around with the device. It seems that the point cloud spreads out a lot.

I guess you are experiencing some drifting.
Drifting happens when you use *Motion Tracking* alone: it consist of a lot of very small error in estimating your *Pose* that all together cause a big error in your pose relative to the world. For instance if you take your tango device and you walk in a circle tracking your `TangoPoseData` and then you draw you trajectory in a spreadsheet or whatever you want you'll notice that the Tablet will never return at his starting point because he is drifting away.
Solution to that is using *Area Learning*.
If you have no clear ideas about this topic i'll suggest watching this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTZZCtmR3OY) from Google I/O 2016. It will cover lots of point and give you a nice introduction.

Using area learning is quite simple.
You have just to change your *base frame of reference* in `TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION`. In this way you tell your Tango to estimate his pose not wrt on where it was when you launched the app but wrt some fixed point in the area.
Here's my code:

```
private static final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> FRAME_PAIRS = 
    new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
{
    FRAME_PAIRS.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE
    ));
}
```

Now you can use this `FRAME_PAIRS` as usual.

Then you have to modify your `TangoConfig` in order to issue Tango to use *Area Learning* using the key `TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION`. Remember that when using `TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION` you CAN'T use learningmode  and load ADF (area description file).
So you cant use:

- `TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LEARNINGMODE`
- `TangoConfig.KEY_STRING_AREADESCRIPTION`

Here's how I initialize `TangoConfig` in my app:

```
TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
//Turning depth sensor on.
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
//Turning motiontracking on.
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING,true);
//If tango gets stuck he tries to autorecover himself.
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_AUTORECOVERY,true);
//Tango tries to store and remember places and rooms,
//this is used to reduce drifting.
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION,true);
//Turns the color camera on.
config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
```

Using this technique you'll get rid of those spreads.

**PS**
In the Talk i linked above, at around 22:35 they show you how to port your application to *Area Learning*. In their example they use <s>`TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_ENABLE_DRIFT_CORRECTION`</s>. This key does not exist anymore (at least in Java API). Use `TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DRIFT_CORRECTION` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm going to try this out asap! I'm not going to render the point cloud while building it. I'll just have to use the pose data and normalize the cloud and THEN write it to the xyz file! Thanks again, I'll let you know if I'm running into trouble.

Comment: I've tried and implemented your solution. It's a lot better than what I had! There still is a problem when I turn around with the device. It seems that the point cloud spreads out a lot. Might I still do something wrong? Or is Project Tango not that precise? If you want to I can give you an example of a scan and the picture of the real life scanned object!

Comment: You experiencing some [drifting](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/motion-tracking#limitations). It can be solved using [Area Learning](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/area-learning). I'm quite busy now, i'll edit this comment with more detail about tomorrow if you need some more help.

Comment: I edited my answer, check if the section about _Drifting_.
Hope this help.