# Tango3DR library in java

Tags: java, android, c++, google-project-tango

I'm trying to use Tango3DR library (that is written in C) in my java code.
I want to have the android life cycle written in java and use this library just for the computation passing object through jni.
I have moderate knowledge in jni syntax and usage, so that's not a problem. What I cant absolutely do is to import the `libtango_3d_reconstruction.so` file i've downloaded from [here](https://developers.google.com/tango/downloads).
The environment is well configured I think , because

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("tango_3d_reconstruction");
}
```

works, and gives no errors or warnings.
But if I try to use this library from c++ code it fails to load the .so file.

I also tried to use this .so in a simple Hello World in c++ using g++ as a compiler, the library is in the correct folder (`/usr/lib`) and I think I used the correct flags for g++ (`g++ main.cpp -o main -ltango_3d_reconstruction`).
This doesn't work and dynamic linker gives me this warning and errors (very similar to the ones in android studio):

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libtango_3d_reconstruction.so when searching for -ltango_3d_reconstruction
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltango_3d_reconstruction
```

I read on the net that this *"skipping incompatible libfoo.so when searching for -lfoo"* happens when there is a mismatch between 32 and 64bit system. I have a 64bit system, so I tried with the `-m32` flag and I got the same error.
I also tried with the `-m64` flag but (as obvious) I got the same again.

Last try: i switched back to my Android Studio, I downloaded the windows 32bit version of NDK and tried out with this; nothing, still skipping.

- Any idea?
- Is `libtango_3d_reconstruction.so` really 32b?

Comment: I'm not sure about the error you are having when compiling using g++, but I can confirm that the library is 32bit, you should be able to check it with file command.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Sadly not. If you may be interested in a java walk-around you can check: [This answer about rotation using Extrinsics and drift correction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243693/generate-and-export-point-cloud-from-project-tango/38267505)  or [This answer about matrix rotation using TangoSupport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949436/project-tango-rotation-and-translation-of-point-clouds-with-area-learning/38087697?noredirect=1#comment63646455_38087697).  
Also [those comments on Google+](https://plus.google.com/101364445131704310015/posts/R7AHDc3dUip) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, by the time any of us have the 3DR C library kluged into a Java app Google might have it in the Java API SDK.